# Should “nature management” be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Should “nature management”¹ be on-topic on TGO?

By “nature management”, I mean questions related to management of publicly accessible recreational land.  For example:

- Why does National Trust Wales choose to actively prevent reforestation (by having sheep grazing)?  In a TV documentary, a National Trust woman said it was necessary to have sheep, “otherwise it would probably just become woodland”
- What kind of vegetation does BLM Utah encourage on its higher-lying public lands and how is this related to hunting?
- What are the pros and cons of suppressing wildfires in a sparsely inhabited Mediterranean climate?
- ...etc...

Such a question is relevant for me as an outdoors person, but it's somewhat tangential as it's rather about management/policy than about how to enjoy the outdoors.

Nature management is a discipline at universities:

- https://www.uni-goettingen.de/en/59550.html
- http://studies.ku.dk/masters/nature-management/
- https://www.bangor.ac.uk/courses/postgraduate/sustainable-forest-and-nature-management-sufonama-msc
- http://www.wageningenur.nl/en/Education-Programmes/prospective-master-students/MSc-programmes/MSc-Forest-and-Nature-Conservation.htm

---

¹I put “nature management” between quotation marks because in my personal opinion, nature should *by definition* not require any management.  However, that is clearly not the way the phrase is used.

Comment: My initial reaction is yes.  TGO has users who love the outdoors, and are very knowledgeable about being in the outdoors.  It is not clear how many users it has who are involved with outdoor management.  Olin Lathrop comes to mind as one who is.  I'd be interested to read what he says on this.   Certainly much of the outdoors we all love and play in is managed.  And neglect is a default option of  management.  I think this, and environmental subjects, are a logical extension of TGO.

Comment: Some of these could be on topic at biology exchange, which includes ecology.

Comment: Another term for this is land management. It's what I've always used in the US.

Answer (score 12):

My general thought to "on-topic" "off-topic" is that we should not be preemptive in our definitions.  Ask the questions.  Nine times out of ten the community will resolve the question without any fuss through their actions.

Comment: yes, don't fix what's not broken